# Is there any possibility to show the source code of flutter objects?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout

I do have a question. I´m programming and I wonder, if there is any possibility to show the standart setting of widgets (Container etc.) or other things.
I looking forward to hear from one of you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the source code of an object, then

Ctrl + (click on the object)

Use ctrl + space for more info

Comment: Thank you really much for answering. I there also a possibility to show the prebuild settings of the widget? I´m using an TextField and I want to understand where I can specify the color. This isn´t mentioned in the class, but when I can see the prebuild setting, I know what dyes the TextField.

Comment: Oh, in my opinion, the official docs are good source, I always use them. You can search TextFiled Flutter, and Flutter docs will have all you need, default settings, properties, methods. :)

Comment: Where do you find the default setting? I can´t see them. :)

Comment: @PhilipLo go to google and search for Text Field or Whatever Widget you are searching for and add flutter after the widget name and you will get the API Docs for those widgets but I have listed how to change the color of Text Field Text That is entered in the below answer please check there.

Comment: I know, I know, but where do you see the default settings. :/

Comment: Use ctrl + space, or flutter docs, or ctrl + click on the object, or hover over the object to get more info about an object. most of the initial values are null, but flutter will yell at you if any object required to have a value.

Comment: I get it what you are asking, and I never wonder that portion, I don't know further.

Answer (score 0):

To see the source code in flutter `Ctrl` and click on the object in windows and if you are on Mac then click `Command` Button and then click on the object and it should show you the source code for the object

Comment: Thank you really much for answering. I there also a possibility to show the prebuild settings of the widget? I´m using an TextField and I want to understand where I can specify the color. This isn´t mentioned in the class, but when I can see the prebuild setting, I know what dyes the TextField.

Comment: @PhilipLo Just add 
style: TextStyle (color: Colors.black) // Or any color you want This would change the color of written stuff in text field